# Is there any way for an actionButton() to navigate to another tab within a R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

I have multiple tabs within my R Shiny app and haven't discovered a way to have my action button navigate to another tab.

The first tab ends with a "submit info" action button, and the goal is to have the "results" tab open after the user submits. If anyone might have some pseudo code that could make this happen, anything would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Share your code/workarounf first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi you can use `updateTabsetPanel` to do that, you have to put an id to your `tabsetPanel` (if you use a `tabsetPanel`) and add `session` to your server function :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "tabs",
    tabPanel(
      title = "params",
      actionButton(inputId = "submitInfo", label = "submit info")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      title = "result",
      "result"
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$submitInfo, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session, inputId = "tabs", selected = "result")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you use a `navbarPage` or `shinydashboard` it works the same way

Comment: This code ended up working! Thanks so much for the help!