# How do you display a table below a plot in a shiny tab?

Tags: r, shiny, render

I've read a few posts ([How can put multiple plots side-by-side in shiny r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384907/how-can-put-multiple-plots-side-by-side-in-shiny-r), [How to RenderTable output to tabPanel in NavBar page + Rshiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52556657/how-to-rendertable-output-to-tabpanel-in-navbar-page-rshiny-app)), but none seem to solve this problem.

I've got two tabs, and in the main panel of each I'd like to display a plot, and then beneath that a table. I can get the plot working, but can't get the table working. I'm not sure if it's the fact I'm using tabs, as I can put the table in alone, without a plot, when there are no tabs.

Here's the script I'm using. I've commented out the `tableOutput('table'))` code that I'd like to use to insert the table because with it in neither the plot or table work!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput(inputId = "sample_1",
                  label = "Select sample 1:",
                  choices = c(unique(instability.data$name))),
      selectInput(inputId = "sample_2",
                  label = "Select sample 2:",
                  choices = c(unique(instability.data$name))),
      selectInput(inputId = "target.channel",
                  label = "Select channel:",
                  choices = channels$name)
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Target", plotlyOutput(outputId = "target")),#, tableOutput('table')),
                  tabPanel("Full", plotlyOutput(outputId = "full")))#, tableOutput('table')))
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$target <- renderPlotly({
    names <- c(input$sample_1, input$sample_2)
    d <- subset(instability.data, name %in% names & channel == input$target.channel & rpt>=start & rpt<=end)
    r <- 
      ggplot(d, aes(x=rpt, y=rfu.rel, fill=name, colour=name)) +
      geom_line(size=0.1) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=start, colour=name), linetype="dotted") +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=end, colour=name), linetype="dotted") +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=control.mode, colour=name), linetype="dashed") +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=ii.threshold, colour=name), linetype="dotted")
    ggplotly(r)
  })
  
  output$full <- renderPlotly({
    names <- c(input$sample_1, input$sample_2)
    d <- subset(instability.data, name %in% names & channel == input$target.channel)
    r <- 
      ggplot(d, aes(x=rpt, y=rfu, fill=name, colour=name)) +
      geom_line(size=0.1) +
      theme_bw() +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=start, colour=name), linetype="dotted") +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=end, colour=name), linetype="dotted") +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=control.mode, colour=name), linetype="dashed") +
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=ii.threshold, colour=name), linetype="dotted")
    ggplotly(r) #%>%
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    t <- subset(instability.summary, name %in% names)
    t[,-1] <- round(t[,-1], 2)
    t
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uncomment the output("table") for *one* tab only ? Shiny doesn't like when 2 outputs have the same id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162511/using-the-same-output-element-twice-in-shiny

Comment: Ah, yes, this works well now! How strange. I'll just create a replica table named something else to go in the second tab. Thanks!

Comment: you can do `output$table1 <- output$table2 <- renderTable({...})` for example

Comment: That also works perfectly, thanks. Incidentally, in this same script I can't get just to work in shiny, but the same code works perfectly outside shiny. I've added the following to the ggplots: geom_text(aes(label=round(peak.rpt, digits=0)), vjust=-1) +